# Weird issue with c++ lambda while capturing "this" pointer

Tags: lambda, cocos2d-x, c++-cx

I implementing Cocos2d-x game on Windows platform. I using Cocos 2.2.2 and VS 2013 Update.

What I trying to do: in game, after user buys successfully item (this is asynchronous operation), I want to update UI with relevant status.

How I trying to do that: I passing lambda to my class responsible for purchasing. Inside callback, if the result is "true" (e.g. success) - I handling UI changes.

Code example:

```
    PurchaseHandler^ handler = ref new PurchaseHandler([this](bool result) -> void
    {
        if (result)
        {
            this->UpdateProductsPurchaseState(); //handle UI after success
        }
    });

    inAppService->RequestProductPurchase(productName, handler); //call to my class responsible for purchases
```

"this" is a class deriving from CCLayer and from CCTargetedTouchDelegate

**Problem**:
When I receive callback, "this" is only partially initialized. Some of the member values seems to be OK, but many of them simply not initialized.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: This is not c++. You need a different language tag.

Comment: You are right, this is a mix of C++ and C++/CX. Tags updated

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, turns out that the problem was before this code, so when I came here my "this" was already corrupted.